# Does twilio functions cover the basic use-case of the twilio conference-call app?

Tags: twilio

My team has been using this basic conference call logic for the last 12-months and really enjoyed having a basic conference call system that is pay-per-use.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls-ruby

I would like to move it into twilio functions, so that our app can stay out of the way. After all, its kinda odd that our app would need to do anything

My code has 2 web callback functions:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Api
  class ConferencesController < WebhooksController
    TWILIO_API_HOST = 'https://api.twilio.com'
    before_action :set_client_and_number, only: [:start_call_record, :broadcast_send, :fetch_recordings, :conference]
    # GET /conference
    def conference
      @conference_number = @twilio_number
    end

    # POST /join
    def join
      response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
      gather = Twilio::TwiML::Gather.new(action: 'connect')
      gather.say("Please Enter The Three Digit Conference Number", voice: 'female')
      response.append(gather)

      render xml: response.to_s
    end

    def connect
      code = params['Digits']

      digits = code.to_s.each_char.to_a
      pronounceable_code = digits.join(" ")
      response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
      response.say("You entered #{pronounceable_code}. You will now join the conference.", voice: 'female')
      dial = Twilio::TwiML::Dial.new
      dial.conference(code)
      response.append(dial)

      render xml: response.to_s
    end

    private

    def set_client_and_number
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
      @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
    end
  end
end
```

JOIN `gathers` a conference room and CONNECT actually connects you to the conference. i've downloaded both XML documents being sent to the server and put them into buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely write these two methods as [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions). You would need to translate the code from Ruby to Node.js though.

Here is a quick (untested) translation that should get you started.

Your initial endpoint, /join in your original code:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const gather = twiml.gather({
    action: '/connect'
  });
  gather.say({ voice: 'female' }, 'Please Enter The Three Digit Conference Number');
  callback(null, twiml);
}
```

Your /connect endpoint:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const code = event.Digits;
  const pronounceableCode = code.toString().split('').join(' ');
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say({ voice: 'female' }, `You entered ${pronounceableCode}. You will now join the conference.`);
  const dial = twiml.dial();
  dial.conference(code);
  callback(null, twiml);
}
```

Make sure you pay attention to the URL paths you use when you create your functions.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That looks pretty good. is the callback response supposed to return XML like the ruby api response is supposed to?

Comment: nevermind! i just found documentation `Twilio Functions will detect the twiml object, then serialize it to XML and set Content-Type: text/xml automatically`

Comment: With a Twilio function once all processing, including asynchronous work, is done you call the `callback` function with your return content. If it's an instance of `Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse` or `MessagingResponse` that will set the content type to `text/xml` and turn the object into it's string/xml representation. The `callback` function takes two arguments, the first is if there is an error, the second is the content.

Comment: Oh, one other thing. Your first endpoint is just static XML really, so you could do that as a [TwiML Bin](http://twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins). That would save any invocation costs on Functions.